# Backpack for Laravel: custom button for opening a popup with the list of entries of related field

Tags: laravel

Good afternoon,
I have a list of players. That table has related fields (like games played).
I'd like to know if there is the possibility to create a custom button in each row of players list that could open a popup with the native datatable with all the games played by that player.
Thank you.